# How to find which index of the expression matches with the regular expression

Tags: c, regex, regular-language

How do I modify this code so that it'll find the index the regex matches with. Basically suppose I had "kim" as my test expression. And my test string is "jkimsdfs". How can I show that "jkimsdfs" matches with "kim" at index 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main () {

        char word[100]; //sets the limit of characters within word to 99(0-99

        char exp[100]; //sets the limit of characters within exp to 99(0-99)

        regex_t w; //contains size_t. This field holds the number of
        //parenthetical subexpressions in the regular expression that was compiled.

        int status; // integer status

        printf("Test Expression: "); //print "Test Expression"

        fgets(word,100,stdin); //

        word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0';
        status = regcomp(&w,word,REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB);
        printf("%d\n", status);
        printf("Validity of regex, if 0 than it matches: %d\n",status);
        if (status) return 1;
        while (1) {
            printf("Test String: ");
            fgets(exp,100,stdin);
            exp[strlen(exp)-1] = '\0';
            if (strlen(exp) < 1)
            break;
            status = regexec(&w,exp,(size_t)0,NULL,0);
            printf("Matched:  %d\n",status);
            printf("%d\n", status);
            }
            regfree(&w);
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Read [`man regcomp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) to find out what `REG_NOSUB` does, then remove it from your code.

Comment: Also, instead of passing 0, NULL to [`regexec()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regexec.3.html), pass the number of elements in, and an array of, `regmatch_t`. The initial element in the array will represent the entire match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strstr`:

```
char str[] = "jkimsdfs";
char *ptr;

if ((ptr = strstr(str, "kim"))) {
     if ((ptr - str) == 1) {
         /* Match */
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the docs say to get a match location it would be

```
size_t     nmatch = 2;
regmatch_t pmatch[2];

status = regexec(&w, exp, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
if ( status == 0 )
{
    printf( "Matched \"%.*s\" at position %d.\n",
         pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so, &exp[pmatch[1].rm_so],
         pmatch[1].rm_so);
}
else
    printf( "Match not found\n" );
```